# How to test if current directory is $HOME?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am converting a shell script into a Python script and having some trouble with testing an IF condition.   In this environment we are running Python 3.9.2.

I originally set 2 variables (homeDir and curDir), create an if-else condition to test if the variables are equal.

Running the script I do a cd to the $HOME directory and run the Python script.

It always prints "False", even when the console output shows the variables are equal.

I am expecting the script to return "Take Action ABC" when running the script in the $HOME directory.

Screen capture showing the output:
[image]

Sample of the code:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

homeDir = Path.home()
curDir = os.getcwd()

print('DEBUG homeDir:', homeDir)
print('DEBUG curDir:', curDir)

if curDir == homeDir:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have objects of different types; `homeDir` is a `Path` object, while `curDir` is a `str`. For that reason they won't compare equal, even if semantically they are the same path. Use one module or the other instead of mixing `pathlib` and `os`. One solution would be to replace

```
os.getcwd()
```

with

```
Path.cwd()
```

The latter is the [`pathlib` equivalent to `os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.cwd).

Example from a Python 3.9 REPL invoked from where my current directory is my user home directory:

```
>>> os.getcwd() == Path.home()
False
>>> Path.cwd() == Path.home()
True
```